# D3.js x-axis error once data reaches 100 value

Tags: d3.js

I modified the code from a D3.js example for a multi line series chart so the x values are numbers instead of dates. The graph works fine as long as the x values are under 100, but once they reach 100 the x-axis reverses order and changes scale (ie: 1 2 3 ... 99) to (100 99.9 99.8 99.7)

Here's the script: http://bitpusher.in/graph.html
and data.tsv: http://bitpusher.in/data.tsv

Any suggestions on how to fix, or where I went wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Okay I sort of fixed the problem by changing the x domain to: x.domain([50, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date; })]); where 50 is the min x value.

Comment: I believe your problem is in your translate. The x-axis is placed in order correctly (if you look at the HTML markup, the text elements go in order down the HTML from least to greatest) but it translates it in such a way that it looks inverse.

Comment: You're using the x values as strings rather than numbers. Everything should work fine if you place a `+` in front of `d.date` when you're assembling `cities`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Thank you, all fixed up!